# avahi-daemon at 50% CPU load on large network

Tags: networking, cpu

I'm currently having problems with my avahi-daemon. I'm connected to my university's network and it seems the large number of other users is somehow flooding my system. The reason I say this is due to the large network is because earlier in the year (before semester started) everything was running smoothly. Disconnecting from the network will kill the cpu load, and reconnecting instantly brings the load back.

I've looked all over the place and there doesn't seem to be good solution to this problem. Can anyone help me?